# xpath: prefix must resolve to a namespace:xsd

Tags: java, maven, binding, namespaces, jaxb

I am a rookie in using jaxb2. I get this error:"xpath: prefix must resolve to a namespace:xsd" and I have no clue how to fix it.
This appen because I have two xsd files that trying to design the same class but in different packages of my java application

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../documentazione/xsd/Global/datatypes_global_v62.xsd">

        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="com.companyname.plugin.entities.global" />
        </jxb:schemaBindings>

        <jxb:bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='Contact']">
            <jxb:class name="GlobalContact" />
        </jxb:bindings>

    </jxb:bindings>


    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../documentazione/xsd/Global/pickupdatatypes_global-3.0.xsd">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="com.companyname.plugin.entities.pickup" />
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:bindings node="xsd://complexType[@name='contact']" >
            <jxb:class name="Contact" />
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
```

I already tried to run the plugin, but I don't know how to fix the error.

Answer (score 6):

How I fix the problem?
Simple! In the name space of my xjb file I was using:

```xml
<jxb:bindings version="2.0" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
    xs:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd">
```

And this was fine for most of my xjb files, but in my case I want to use complexType node. In this case I have to use:

```xml
<jxb:bindings version="2.0"  xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
    xs:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd">
```

the `xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` help me to fix all my issue.